# "He is John's dad, whom may be coming." -- is this sentence grammatical?

Tags: grammar

Should it use 'who' or 'whom', and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be "who" because John's dad is performing the action of "coming". That is "John's dad" is the *subject* of the verb "coming". "Whom" is used for the *object* of the verb, for example "It was John's dad *to whom* I sent the invitation".

Having said that "whom" is not used much in ordinary conversation these days, most people would say "It was John's dad who I sent the invitation to" or, more likely, "It was John's dad *that* I sent the invitation to" or even "It was John's dad I sent the invitation to".

If in doubt use "who" in ordinary conversation. Using "whom" incorrectly would be a big mistake and even using "whom" correctly can make you sound pretentious.lk

Answer (score 0):

The rules to follow for correct use of 'who' and 'whom' are:

1. Use 'who'.

Comment: In older forms of English, there was a word 'whom' which served a similar purpose to some modern uses of 'who', when we use 'who' as an object. The difference is the same as between 'he' and 'him'. You would use 'who' where you would use he/she and 'whom' where you would use 'him'/'her'. Thus 'Who is it?', 'He is John's dad, who might be coming.', 'You told my secret to whom?', 'She hit whom?'